# Storing the contents of a photo album in NoSQL

Tags: python, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Further to this question:

> [Proper NoSQL data schema for web photo gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948767/proper-nosql-data-schema-for-web-photo-gallery)

In MySQL, retrieving the contents of an album would have looked like this:

```
SELECT photos.*, albums.album_title
FROM photos, albums_to_photos, albums
wHERE albums_to_photos.photo_id = photos.photo_id AND
      albums_to_photos.album_id = albums.album_id AND
      album_title = 'Family Vacation'
```

This would have retrieved a list of all photos from the album "Family Vacation"

One way I was thinking of is to create a table called "albums" and to store the photo ids of all the photos within the value field. For example:

```
{_id:'Family Vacation',
 values:'25, 512, 6172, 16923, 168253, 79185892'}
```

And then performing a multi select for each of those values to lookup the photo ids to actual photo items. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4f30153eecd1ab7c49ded566"),
   "album": "Family Vacation",
   "photo": "25"
},
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4f30153eecd1ab7c49ded565"),
   "album": "Family Vacation",
   "photo": "512"
}
```

Store each photo separately, if you want to at some point add more photo info such as titles it's easier to manage. Also consider using id's to reference your albums. Then you can do something like:

->find(array( "album" => "Family Vacation" ))

Comment: The schema above would be for a table called "albums?"

Comment: They are called collections in NoSQL, but yes, you would create a new collection called albums. Also, collections are schema-less.

Answer (score 0):

Stur, correct if i'm wrong, but filter by a column will do a full table scan right?
If so, i believe that the solution presented by Ensnare will work better with a bigger data.

Ensnare, assuming for the tag, you use dynamodb, you can use an Set of Integer for the photo ID, but you will need to work with the 64kb per row limit.

You can also create an secondary index, using the album name as primary key, and photoid as range key.

Comment: I don't see any advantage in storing photo id's as a comma separated string in NoSQL. It violates 1NF, so you would run into all sorts of problems - can't order your selection, can't ensure data type, not to mention being able to add/remove photos from the album.

Comment: In dynamoDB(assuming he uses it) doesn't need to be comma separated, you can use Set of String or Number with it(no sure how it handles internally though). But I think you are right, there is some big complications, order and add/delete will certainly be an pain. The solution then is create your own Secondary Index, do you agree?